# CodeIgniter 4: Class "Company\PostTranslator\Models\TranslateCategoryModel" not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

FIXED: I have been trying programming in CodeIgniter 4. Things were going great until I hit this roadblock. I have researched thru the code, CI docs and searched online without a solution to this issue and I don't understand why CI cannot see that file. One thing to note is that in the IDE this class is mapped correctly (IE. I can control -> click on the Class initialization call and it will take me to the correct file. I need some help as I cannot see where the problem is.

**ERROR**: `CRITICAL Class "Company\PostTranslator\Models\TranslateCategoryModel" not found`

**Application structure**

- app
- assets
- modules

  - Company

    - PostTranslator

      - Models

        - TranslateCategoryModel.php
- writable
- ...

This is how I have it setup:

**app/Config/Autload.php (PSR4)**

```
public $psr4 = [
    APP_NAMESPACE => APPPATH, // For custom app namespace
    'Config'      => APPPATH . 'Config',
    'Company\PostTranslator' => ROOTPATH . 'modules/Company/PostTranslator',
];
```

**modules/Company/PostTranslator/Models/TranslateModel.php**

```
<?php

namespace Company\PostTranslator\Models;

use Company\PostTranslator\Models\TranslateCategoryModel;
use App\Models\PostAdminModel;

class TranslateModel extends PostAdminModel
{
    public $translateCategoryModel;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->translateCategoryModel = new TranslateCategoryModel();
    }

    public function addTranslatedPost($postData, $translatedContent)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

**modules/Company/PostTranslator/Models/TranslateCategoryModel.php**

```
<?php

namespace Company\PostTranslator\Models;

use App\Models\CategoryModel;

class TranslateCategoryModel extends CategoryModel
{   
    ...
}
```

I don't see what I am possibly doing wrong.

---

The following for example, works without issues

**modules/Company/PostTranslator/Config/Events.php**

```
<?php

namespace Company\PostTranslator\Config;

use CodeIgniter\Events\Events;

Events::on('pre_system', function () {
    log_message('error', "FIRING EVENT pre_system");
});
```

**LOG FILE ENTRY**
`ERROR - 2023-02-13 10:48:16 --> FIRING EVENT pre_system`

Answer (score 0):

You should run `composer dump-autoload`

**EDIT:**

The key of each row is the namespace itself. This does not need a trailing back slash. The value is the location to the directory the classes can be found in. They should have a trailing slash. [Codeigniter Documentation](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/concepts/autoloader.html?highlight=autoload#namespaces)

So you have to change the `$psr4` like this:

```
public $psr4 = [
    APP_NAMESPACE => APPPATH, // For custom app namespace
    'Company\PostTranslator' => ROOTPATH . 'modules/Company/PostTranslator/',
];
```

Possible explanation why the The following for example, works without issues

**modules/Company/PostTranslator/Config/Events.php** works without issues is because this is not a Class, so even if you add namespaces above it, doesn't affect at all (you can try to remove namespace for the Config).

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I have run the following just now but still the same error: composer dump-autoload, composer clear-cache, removed composer.lock, composer install

Comment: but I still have the same issue. Same error

Comment: I've just updated the answer, try to check that out

Comment: I updated according to your answer by adding / in the of the path, but still not luck. Same error.

Answer (score 0):

The file's extension was removed somehow. IDE did not detect the problem and neither did I. I only was able to figure out after I tried require. I am mad!